# How should you design/set colors/export a document with 'equal' colors both on screen and print?

Tags: print-design, cmyk, rgb, color-conversion

What's the best approach to create a document that is both suited for digital viewing (Monitor, iPhone, etc.) and for print?

I'm creating some personal branding, which includes an invoice that will be sent digital, but of course might be printed. I'm using a CMYK InDesign preset and I'm using Turquoise (71,0,31,0) as a base color. When I export it, any setting, it shows great on my Macbook, but my iPhone shows a rather very light green color, instead of turquoise. I haven't printed it, yet.

My problem is I want both print and 'web' have great colors, but there should be compromises as CMYK and RGB aren't the same. I wouldn't mind if it showed up a bit different on print, but every digital device great, but that's not happening right now, sadly.

What should be my best approach?

Comment: Digital invoice that might be printed sounds like something that might as well be rgb.

Comment: Your monitor is calibrated to show sRGB?

Comment: I don't know, actually but I think so? It's a 2012 Macbook Pro :)

Comment: There is no real way to get it to show up *exactly* the same across all mediums.  Different screen calibrations, different color modes...the best you can do is get it somewhat close.

One thing that I immediately think of is which color mode you saved your PDF in.  I would suggest saving it as an interactive PDF which will convert it to RGB.  If you're trying to view a CMYK document in the browser on your phone, the colors can sometimes be skewed.

Comment: I don't mind if it differs a bit, but on my Macbook it's turquoise, but on my phone it's very bright green. The one is nice for the eye, the other one hurts. If say, 5% different color, meh. But this isn't even comparable. I know not every medium, even the same type (i.e. monitors) has the same colors. I'm just looking for a way where red looks red, green looks green, and turquoise looks turquoise, on both screen and paper. That's all. I will create a RGB document and test it, instead of CMYK as you and Joonas suggest. We'll see. Any other suggestions? :)